# Why did this txn not transfer balance, I passed the exact same string same hex as response set in question

Tags: solidity

I called https://etherscan.io/address/0x0c63bf5f9c1b31bd98eb2995e8ab5ba33fe31d22 contract's Try function by passing the same string which was passed in Start function. I checked hex. Can someone help me why Try function call https://etherscan.io/tx/0x096a060d64d833c55fd83b2ea4ec209578dc3316d863de3a3de63692e8476628
did not initiate balance transfer. Is there something, I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Quiz is a scam contract

The authors usually use a set of similar names (`[a-z]{2}_quiz`), but most of them contain the same code and act as a honeypot scam.

Read more about it:

- https://medium.com/coinmonks/do-not-be-fooled-by-crypto-quiz-games-f38f72a53c78
- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62815/trying-to-figure-out-this-2-eth-smart-contract-quiz

---

**How the scam works:**

The attacker uses internal call from another contract *(that doesn't appear on the honeypot "transactions" or "internal calls" lists)* to call the `New()` function and set the hash to some garbage value.

This garbage value is not the hash of the string passed in the `Start()` function and most probably not even a hash of any string.

Then publicly calls the `Start()` function (see [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x064bf9abc1c500d6b224b75caf957c039cddb027163e3649c22902a81d18fb02)), so that it looks like they are setting the hash, but it's not set because of this condition:

```
if(responseHash==0x0){  // it's not 0x0 anymore
    responseHash = keccak256(abi.encode(_response));
    question = _question;
}
```

Comment: Normally one does not give kudos here in comments, but I must say your warning is excellent.